# What's the relation between irreducible representation and $d$-vector?

Tags: group-theory, superconductivity, representation-theory

In many papers, especially these related to the triplet superconductor, the superconductor order parameter, the d-vector, always appears together with the irreducible representation of the space group. Such as the following picture which presents the relation between irreducible representation and the order parameter of $Sr_2RuO_4$.

[image]

And my question is what's the one-to-one correspondence between the irreducible representation and the order parameter?